A movie about a sick kid in a hospital
A long time ago I watched a movie that was about a sick kid who was in hospital. The movie was probably from mid 00's. 
The dad was running to the hospital to his daughter and to do something it may have been to stop going to surgery . The kid was in a very big room with other sick kids next to the kid. I think the kid went into surgery in the same place. 
I remember this scene where the kid was walking around in the hospital with her dad and she may have been holding a teddy bear. 
The scenes are very blurry to me so I may have gotten them wrong. I think the kid was cured at the end and was in a car with the dad or something. 
The kid was probably diagnosed with cancer or was being donated a part of the body or maybe donating I don't know.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Unfortunately that was all I remember. I'm not even sure if the kid was a girl or a boy. As I said before it was a really long time ago, maybe 8 or 9 years ago.
